# Authentication when combining Web and Mobile Apps in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I follow this article: [develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter6/mvc/)
for combining my already fonctional Xamarin app with an small web site use by some admins. In the article, we only need to add this in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/.auth/login/aad" defaultUrl="/Home" timeout="480"/>
</authentication>
```

This addition work good, but after logging in and click on the ugly link "Return to you web site" provided by Azure, I always got redirect on the root of the site (that display: This mobile app is up and running). I try to add defaultUrl to redirect to the /Home page without success.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not set the "Allowed External Redirect URLs".  This feature allows you to call the authentication backend with a specific Redirect URL.  On a successful authentication, it then redirects to one of the valid authentication redirects.  You need to specify the url during the request by specifying a `post_login_redirect_url`.  For example:

```
<forms loginUrl="/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=/Home/Index" timeout="480"/>
```

For more information, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to)